# How do I solve Xamarin 'Failed to start application on the target simulator'?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.ios, osx-yosemite, parallels

This is obviously not a new failure. Though, I have tried the solutions I found on Xamarin Forum. I am new with development on Xamarin and running Visual Studio 2013 inside Parallels since VS is the only way for easy true cross-platform development with Xamarin (using trial license).

I got it working for Windows Phone (of course) and also for Android but I really tried many hours now to get it working for iOS as well but no. I do have paired my build host in my mac to my visual studio.

I get the following error when I try to run the iPhoneSimulator (iPhone 4s iOS 8.3) (debug/release)

> Failed to start application on the target simulator
>
> Server returned an error. The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized. Server error code: 401 Unauthorized You are not
>   authorized to run this command

Solutions already tried;

- Made sure build host and visual studio are using latest stable version of Xamarin - No
- Paired, unpaired and paired again... multiple times - No
- Emptied Xamarin cache in my Parallels instance and unpaired and paired again - No
- Tried cleaning solution, changing info.plist to copy always, doing release build and then a debug build - No
- Tried to remove the dot '.' in assembly name - No
- Tried multiple restarts of both parallels as well as my Mac host - No
- Made sure my App is building for iOS 8.3 - No
- Firewalls turned off on both guest and host - No diff

These are all others solutions but none worked for me.

Comment: Try disabling the firewall, both on the Mac and the VM.

Comment: Thanks, it was already turned off so unfortunately no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that run into the same issue I can tell that Xamarin did identify a bug that comes from the fact that I didn't have default regional settings, Ie. my regional settings are swedish. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/150417#Comment_150417